# Integrals of multiple variables with some of the limits depending on variables (Julia)

Tags: julia, integral

Suppose that there is data on J variables, Y_1, Y_2,..., Y_J, drawn from multivariate normal distribution. I am trying to calculate the marginal cdf of Y_1 conditional on Y_1>=Y_2>=...>=Y_J. While I'm doing this, I need to do integration over Y_1,...,Y_J with ranges [-inf,y] for Y_1, [-inf, Y_1] for Y_2, ..., [-inf, Y_J-1] for Y_J.

What I am currently doing is to create many inner integrals and do it sequentially. But I want to make it flexible for the order of Ys or calculating the marginal cdf of Y_j. Is there any easier way to do integrals of multiple variables with some limits depending on variables?

Comment: If you give a MWE (minimum working example), or add *running code* which demonstrates the question, the response would be better

Comment: This question does not refer to programming. Please post on an appropriate StackExchange site (e.g. Cross Validated)

Answer (score 0):

One option, if you are using a package like [HCubature.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/HCubature.jl) or [Cuba.jl](https://github.com/giordano/Cuba.jl) that does integration over hyper-rectangle domains, is simply to do a change of variables that maps your domain to a rectangle.  See, for example, [this Julia discourse post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/2d-integration-over-non-rectangular-domain-using-cubature/2991/6).

Alternatively, there is a package [IteratedIntegration.jl](https://github.com/lxvm/IteratedIntegration.jl) to do nested integrals more efficiently.